# S3A class working on driver but not executor

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, hadoop, pyspark

I have docker images created using Spark 3.3.4 `docker-image-tool.sh`, using the supplied Dockerfiles for the base and pyspark.

Running on EKS 1.29 with latest `spark-operator` using base image I created above for the `SPARK_IMAGE` arg in building the operator image, but with the `hadoop-aws` and `aws-java-sdk-bundle` jars already installed.

Submitting a `SparkApplication` that uses `s3a://` for main application file, `pyFiles`, `files`, and is used in the path for `spark.read.parquet()` calls.

The operator submits fine (pulling the main application file from s3a://.  The driver pulls the pyfiles and files fine and appears to do some S3 calls to get a feel for the parquet.  The executor fails with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)
```

SparkApplication:

```
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: spark-${RUN_ID}
  namespace: spark
spec:
  type: Python
  #pythonVersion: "3"
  mode: cluster
  image: "mjans71/spark-py:3.3.4"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainApplicationFile: "s3a://${S3_BUCKET}/app/app.py"
  sparkVersion: "3.3.4"
  restartPolicy:
    type: Never
  deps:
    packages:
      - "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.2"
    pyFiles:
      - "s3a://${S3_BUCKET}/app/pyfiles.zip"
    files:
      - "s3a://${S3_BUCKET}/app/files.tar.gz"
  driver:
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: "1200m"
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 3.3.4
    serviceAccount: spark-driver
    env:
      - name: STORAGE_PATH
        value: "s3a://${S3_BUCKET}/data"
      - name: RESULTS_PATH
        value: "s3a://${S3_BUCKET}/results"
      - name: RUN_ID
        value: "${RUN_ID}"
      - name: QUERY_GLOB
        value: "*"
  executor:
    cores: 4
    instances: 4
    serviceAccount: spark-driver
    memory: "512m"
    affinity:
      podAntiAffinity:
        requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: spark-role
              operator: In
              values:
              - executor
          topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
  sparkConf:
    "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "-Divy.cache.dir=/tmp -Divy.home=/tmp"
    "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions": "-Divy.cache.dir=/tmp -Divy.home=/tmp"
```

From the `spark-operator` pod logs, here's the `spark-submit` executed to submit the application:

```
/opt/spark/bin/spark-submit \
    --master k8s://https://10.100.0.1:443 \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark \
    --conf spark.app.name=spark-1 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=spark-1-driver \
    --files s3a://bucketname/app/queries.tar.gz \
    --py-files s3a://bucketname/app/pyfiles.zip \
    --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.2 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=mjans71/spark-py:3.3.4 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.submission.waitAppCompletion=false \
    --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Divy.cache.dir=/tmp -Divy.home=/tmp \
    --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Divy.cache.dir=/tmp -Divy.home=/tmp \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/app-name=spark-1 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/launched-by-spark-operator=true \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/submission-id=b0d78417-6a5d-4be4-b056-c18713bdbbc6 \
    --conf spark.driver.cores=1 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.limit.cores=1200m \
    --conf spark.driver.memory=512m \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark-driver \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.label.version=3.3.4 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/app-name=spark-1 \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/launched-by-spark-operator=true \
    --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.label.sparkoperator.k8s.io/submission-id=b0d78417-6a5d-4be4-b056-c18713bdbbc6 \
    --conf spark.executor.instances=4 \
    --conf spark.executor.cores=4 \
    --conf spark.executor.memory=512m \
    s3a://bucketname/app/run-queries.py
```

Shouldn't the `spec.packages` / `--packages` specified ensure that both the driver and executor have the necessary files?

EDIT: The executors are failing and being deleted too quickly for me to get their logs.

EDIT: I found the `spark.kubernetes.executor.deleteOnTermination` setting and was able to get the logs from the executors.  I'm not seeing anywhere in the logs where the `hadoop-aws` package jars are being downloaded from the driver.

EDIT: I've tried also adding the JAR files that are retrieved with the hadoop-aws package to both /opt/spark/jars and /opt/spark/work-dir, with both including and omitting the --package flag.  Same error.  [Here's the full driver log](https://gist.github.com/MikeJansen/b46b19b3b97718fa9c88b34bb3d8c8d0), which I'm assuming is showing exceptions from the executor as well because it's succeeding with S3A and then showing it can't find the class.